# How to get coordinates of current mouse click in leaflet react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

I'm trying to get coordinates of where the mouse clicks on the map but .locate() only returns the center coordinates of the map.
Is there a way?
ps. I am not using class based react.
Thanks

```
 <MapContainer
          center={[ 33.8735578, 35.86379]}
        zoom={9}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
  
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
</MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get coordinates of mouse click by `useMapEvents` hook.

try this one.

```
const MapEvents = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      click(e) {
        // setState your coords here
        // coords exist in "e.latlng.lat" and "e.latlng.lng"
        console.log(e.latlng.lat);
        console.log(e.latlng.lng);
      },
    });
    return false;
}

    return (
       <MapContainer
          center={[ 33.8735578, 35.86379]}
          zoom={9}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
       >
          <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a 
           href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
           url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
            <MapEvents />
    </MapContainer>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Question and where is your code? You are not new to this site so you should know to show what you have done so far.
Okay, I will be gracious today ;)
I don't want to cut and clean the code, so I paste as is.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, useMap, TileLayer, } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import tileLayer from '../util/tileLayer';

const center = [52.22977, 21.01178];

const GetCoordinates = () => {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    const info = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend');

    const positon = L.Control.extend({
      options: {
        position: 'bottomleft'
      },

      onAdd: function () {
        info.textContent = 'Click on map';
        return info;
      }
    })

    map.on('click', (e) => {
      info.textContent = e.latlng;
    })

    map.addControl(new positon());

  }, [map])


  return null

}

const MapWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={18} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer {...tileLayer} />

      <GetCoordinates />

    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default MapWrapper;
```

Comment: hello, thanks for helping , for my code I only yet have the <MapContainer> with the <TitleLayer/>, but this didn't work, the just won't render now. with this error : 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DomUtil')'

Comment: nevermind I was importing L wrongly, thankss anyways!

Comment: just a comment, that if you use useMapEvents({...}) instead of useMap() you will avoid returning the location more than once in zoom .